# Pasé Javascript a $_POST php, pero mysqli duplica la entrada

Tags: javascript, php, sql, formularios, variables

En 1 archivo una variable toma la fecha y hora, la guarda en $_POST automáticamente con Js, echo la imprime, otra variable hace la conexión y se guarda en database phpmyadmin.

Demostración:

```
<?php


//Variable del script:

$timedata = "
<form id='form' method='POST' name='form'>
     <input type='text' id='date' name='date' value=''/>
     <input type='submit' id='datesubmit'>
</form>

<script type='text/JavaScript'>

const Timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

let d = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').value = d.getDate() +'-'+ d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear() +' '+ d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() +' '+ ' timezone:' + Timezone;

var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
var datos = new FormData(form);
fetch('question.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    })
});

document.getElementById('datesubmit').click();

</script>";

echo $timedata;

//Conexión: 

$post = $_POST['date'];
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=0.0.0.0;dbname=wooddocu_db', "root", "root"); 
$connection = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users(date) VALUES('$post')");


?>
```

Resultado:

[image: formulario]

Guarda una con la fecha hora exacta y otra vacía:

[image: DataBase]

¿Cómo se puede interceptar la vacía o que guarde una solamente?

**CORREGIDO:**

```
<?php
if ($post = $_POST['date']??null) {//COMPRUEBA QUE EXISTA LA VARIABLE Y SOLO APLICA SI EXISTE
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=0.0.0.0;dbname=wooddocu_db', "root", "root");
    $connection = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users(date) VALUES('$post')");//Esto lo tienes que mejorar porque es un problema de seguridad grave. Revisa la documentación en https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php
    exit;//Con esto cortas la ejecución del script
};

//Variable del script:

$timedata = "
<form id='form' method='POST' name='form'>
    <input type='text' id='date' name='date' value=''/>
    <input type='submit' id='datesubmit'>
</form>

<script type='text/JavaScript'>

const Timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

let d = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').value = d.getDate() +'-'+ d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear() +' '+ d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() +' '+ ' timezone:' + Timezone;

var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
var datos = new FormData(form);
fetch('question.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    })
});

document.getElementById('datesubmit').click();

</script>";

echo $timedata;

$post = $_POST['date'];
?>
```

Funciona.
Captura datos del usuario, atravez de un formulario, sin que presione el botón enviar, pasa cualquier funcion javascript a php.

Tiene un fetch nombrando al propio archivo,  se envia a si mismo el POST. Sirve en login, inicio de seción, etc. se agrega con require o include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada, si tienes un código HTML y Javascript utilízalos correctamente fuera de las etiquetas de PHP.

No tienes ninguna necesidad de escribir HTML en PHP cuando puedes hacerlo fuera de las etiquetas.

Primero haz solo el HTMl y el Javascript y olvídate de las etiquetas PHP.

Una vez el formulario te haya quedado como corresponde con una estructura correcta del HTML, te puedes enfocar en el almacenado.
Si quieres usar un solo archivo pon el código PHP arriba del sitio web tipo:

```
<?php
if ($post = $_POST['date']??null) {//COMPRUEBA QUE EXISTA LA VARIABLE Y SOLO APLICA SI EXISTE
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=0.0.0.0;dbname=wooddocu_db', "root", "root");
    $connection = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users(date) VALUES('$post')");//Esto lo tienes que mejorar porque es un problema de seguridad grave. Revisa la documentación en https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php
    exit;//Con esto cortas la ejecución del script
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id='form' method='POST' name='form'>
    <input type='text' id='date' name='date' value=''/>
    <input type='submit' id='datesubmit'/>
</form>

<script type='text/JavaScript'>

    const Timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

    let d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('date').value = d.getDate() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + ' ' + ' timezone:' + Timezone;

    var form = document.getElementById('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos = new FormData(form);
        fetch('question.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: datos
        })
    });

    document.getElementById('datesubmit').click();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No voy a corregirte el código pero así es como deberías organizarlo.
Si prestas atención el código PHP está arriba para impedir duplicados de información y pues no imprimir código HTML cuando no es necesario. (Por eso el 'exit')

Comment: Tienes razón, lo mostré sencillo, pero es complejo jejeje.
Esto es un controlador php que se incluye en los envíos de datos que controlan el login, inicio de seción, crear un post, comentar, crud, etc. que a su vez estan en el HTML !DOCTYPE, se usa para tomar informacion del usuario ej. Dónde vive, ciudad, localizacion, ip, gps, huella del navegador, users agente, cpu, plataforma, cores del procesador, cookies, caches, seciones, etc.

Comment: En este caso la fecha hora y zona horaria exactas de su dispositivo con un script, esta más cerca del servidor que del usuario, más oculto y seguro, para que no se vea fácilmente. Pasa variables, datos o funciones Javascript a php a la base de datos con un archivo sencillo, sin usar el Ajax, jQuery, json, $_GET o XMLHttp.
Y me funcionó tu idea gracias, pero sin HTML.

Comment: En realidad el archivo requiere una sola vez la conexión pdo que está dentro de una función en un php aparte que también tiene un limpiador de cadenas e inyección sql .Después de require llama a la función conexión y usa prepare para enviar datos. Todo eso es seguro? que más seguridad puedo dar sobre todo este archivo?

Answer (score 0):

estas llamando 2 veces a la misma pagina, cuando se muestra y cuando le enviás la información

tienes que dejar el php en otra pagina o validar los datos por post, si vienen se inserta, de lo contrario no se hace.

Comment: En el echo? lo saqué y borra las dos.

Comment: En un solo archivo envió de Javascript a php y a phpmyadmin, guarda correctamente toda la informacion, hay una función para corregir ese pequeño error?